# How to calculate charge transfer (CT) in NBO Analysis using Gaussian 09?

Tags: computational-chemistry, gaussian, charge-transfer

I have a coronene structure, functionalized with hydroxyl groups.
I want to calculate the charge transfer (CT) between the coronene and the hydroxyl group, using NBO analysis as implemented in Gaussian 09.

I understand that I should use the Hirshfeld population, but apart from that, how is it done?